An 'if' statement isn't executing when a mask is applied to a variable even though it should
In my example, I’m creating an integer variable called testVar and I make it equal to A1 in hexadecimal. When printing out the variable, it shows that it should indeed be equal to A1 in hexadecimal. Now when checking if testVar is equal to A1 in an if statement, the if statement only executes when there isn't any mask applied to the variable.
Why don't these if statements execute when the variable has a mask applied to it?
#include <stdio.h>

int testVar = 0xA1;   // testVar should be equal 0x000000A1 now

void main() {
    printf("%x \n", testVar);               // Should prove that testVar is indeed equal to A1 in hexadecimal
    printf("%x \n", testVar & 0x000000FF);  // Both printf functions are outputting a1

    if (testVar == 0x000000A1) {      // This 'if' statement works!
        printf("success1");
    }
    if (testVar & 0x000000FF == 0x000000A1) { // This doesn't execute
        printf("success2");
    }
    if (testVar & 0x000000FF == 0xA1) { // This doesn't execute
        printf("success3");
    }
}


Welcome to SO. You need to take a look into your operator precedence table. == has higher precedence than &. That means your condition is same as testVar & (0x000000ff == 0x000000a1) which is same as testVar & 0. You need to use ((testVar & 0x000000ff) == 0x000000a1)

No compiler warning? MSVC gives that without Wall

gcc and clang will give a warning when compiling with -Wall.

Aside: Where did you learn to use void main() { ... }?

There must be tons of duplicates for this. This is adding unnecessary redundancy.

cont' - Where is the canonical question?

The 'why' question (not really a duplicate): Operator precedence (bitwise '&' lower than '=='). "Why do the bitwise operators (& and |) have lower precedence than the equality operator (==)?"

A starting point (low-scored duplicate): Why do bitwise operators require parentheses? (2017)

Where is the canonical question?

Is between the logical AND and OR operators (not a duplicate and not bitwise operators): C++ Binary operators order of precedence (2008)

Other sets of operators (not duplicates): Priority of C++ operators "&" and "->" and Operator precedence C++

The question remains: Where is the canonical question?

The equality operator == has higher precedence than the binary bitwise AND operator &.  That means that this:
if (testVar & 0x000000ff == 0x000000a1)

Parses as this:
if (testVar & (0x000000ff == 0x000000a1))

Which is not what you want.  Use parentheses to ensure proper grouping:
if ((testVar & 0x000000ff) == 0x000000a1)

And similarly:
if ((testVar & 0x000000ff) == 0xa1)

